# mysql reduce counter if positive

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to implement a simple credit system, so I have a column "credits" in my user table, and I'd like to do the following with PHP/MySQL:

```
if (credits >= 1)  
  credits = credits - 1;
else 
  error(not_enough_credits);
```

Is it possible to do this in one query? Obviously, I could do a `SELECT` query on the credits, and if that is >=1 do an `UPDATE` to reduce the counter by one, but that could give concurrency issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE myTable SET credits = (credits - 1)  WHERE credits > 0
```

That where will work like an `if` in this case. This will also work fine for multiple users separately, given you provide it a valid user id.

```
UPDATE myTable SET credits = (credits - 1)  WHERE id=12345 AND credits > 0
```

Comment: Interesting. And how can I read from the result if the counter was actually decreased?

Comment: You can check for the number of affected rows after this query. Which API do you use for MySQL connection? Method depends on that

Comment: One more thing to keep in mind, this update will lock all the rows with credits 0. Hence, if you are executing this update from an application and if the application has other modules/processes which utilize this process, it is likely that those processes will get hung as long as this update executes. Hence, best way of doing this is to stop the application and fire the query (if possible).

Comment: That is wrong. If this update is being applied to only one user's data, it wont lock every row.

Comment: Thanks, didn't think of that, that works perfectly! And as for the comments above on the locking, as far as I know that depends on the choice of the table structure (MyISAM which blocks the entire table, vs InnoDB which blocks only row-by-row). But luckily this is not a problem for my application.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `CASE` statement, like this:

```
UPDATE table1
SET credits = CASE WHEN credits >= 1 THEN credits-1 END
```

Comment: Solution using where clause is better, as assuming you have an index on credits, you would not need to touch every row and gave the case statement evaluated during query execution.

Comment: @MikeBrant ah missed the indexing part. Thanks for the pointer.